# Having trouble understanding ASTnode, SourceCode, Token in JavaScript after reading ESlint docs

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint, lint, eslintrc

I have been working on writing a ESlint plugin to enfore a convention in module import order for my company. I am completely new to writing ESlint rules/plugins and been reading the docs.

I found there's really no formal definitions for these three concepts in the ESlint docs:
`ASTnode`, `SourceCode`, `Token`

I tried to add console.log to print these variables in some eslint rule files but it isn't working.

Hope someone can help me on this and point out why I cannot use console.log in the rule as we would normally do to print out intermediate variables

Comment: https://github.com/estree/estree did you read this?

Comment: Check out https://astexplorer.net/ (disclaimer: I wrote that)

Comment: @Felix Kling I know this website and thank you for the amazing work but I still don't know what SourceCode, Token are